# Is this a valid test?

Tags: r, sampling, p-value, validity

I have 5000 cases vs 5000 controls with positive/negative outcome. `chi.test` shows no significance for this data. I get significance when subsetting cases on *VarX*, 1000 cases vs 5000 controls.

I suspect that doing 1000 cases vs 5000 controls makes up the significance. To eliminate this I am randomly picking 1000 controls and running `chi.test` 1000 times vs 1000 cases.

Here is the histogram of pvalues and the red line is `Pvalue` for 1000 cases vs 5000 controls:
[image]

From this can I conclude that there is no significance?
If there is a better way of doing this please advise.

Comment: First, a test can't show "no significance" - it gives a particular p value. Second I don't understand exactly what you mean by "subsetting on varX", nor exactly what you are bootstrapping. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: After testing for all cases 5K vs all controls 5K pvalue is >0.05, not significant. I am trying to find out if there is a significance for the subset of cases `dat[ dat$caco==0 | dat$varX=="A",]`, i.e. all controls vs cases with varX=="A", here I have pvalue <0.05.

Comment: In that case, you don't need to do anything else, just say what you did when you report results. However, beware that with 5000 vs. 1000 even very small differences can be significant.

Comment: *5000 vs. 1000 even very small differences can be significant.* - that is my worry, hence I came up with above "method" - as a way of validation. (Apologies, I'm not a statistician.)

Comment: Your method doesn't fix that and isn't necessary. Just look at the effect sizes - here, the proportions in each cell of your table.

Comment: It sounds as if you would like to say, based on the smaller-sample test, whether the larger-sample test "deserved" to have a significant result.  To go along with what @PeterFlom said, a better (and by the way much more accepted) way is to assess just how different the full set of cases and controls are.  A p-value can be treated as supplementary to that, to say something about whether the result looks like a fluke.  But from what you say you also may want to think about cross-validating, using one method or another.